# Switch fluently from one window to another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Home window with a "New Project" button. If the user clicks the "New Project" button I currently open my Project window:

```
Project project = new Project();
project.Show();
```

But what I really want is that my Home window disappears and the Project window appears at the same position/size. Like Microsoft Word 2019. You start the program, Home screen appears. You click New, page view appears at the same position/size.

At the moment after project.Show() the Project window appears, but jumps some pixel to right and bottom.

How I can achieve this?

Should I change my Project window to something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. It might not be exactly what you want, but it will at least be close- plus it's easy:

When you create your new `Project` window, set the `Height`, `Width`, `Top` and `Left` properties to match those of the `Home` window. This will cause the `Project` window to open in the same exact place as the `Home` window. Just remember you have to close your `Home` window first before showing `Project`.

Example code:

```
Project W = new Project() { Height = this.Height, Width = this.Width, Left = this.Left, Top = this.Top };
Close();
W.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tested that and it don't work if the the user first moves the window to another position.

Comment: @tildebox I just tested it and no matter how much I move or resize the first window, the second one always shows up in the exact same place. I just updated my answer with some example code. Make sure you're not doing anything else to influence the startup position like setting `WindowStartupLocation` or something.